# Options for importing modules in Angular2 (TS)

Tags: typescript, angular, systemjs, visual-studio-code

I know there's some progress or at least plans ([#5093](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5039), [#5728](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/5728)) to improve typescript's module paths mapping, but I was wondering what are our options at this moment (Angular2 beta.1, TypeScript 1.7, VS Code 0.10.5, nodejs 5.4, systemjs 0.19).

In order to make *everyone* happy (compiler, editor and browser) I'm using following syntax to import modules:

```
// C:/~somepath~/project_name/src/scripts/app/components/search/search.component.ts
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {EmitterService} from '../../../core/services/emitter/emitter.service';
import {SearchService} from '../../../app/services/search/search.service';
```

which compiles to

```
System.register(['angular2/core', '../../../core/services/emitter/emitter.service'], function(exports_1) {
```

when I use following options

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
    ...
  }  
}
```

I'd like to use imports without all those dots:

```
import {EmitterService} from 'core/services/emitter/emitter.service';
```

since it's getting pretty ugly, crazy to track and a nightmare to move modules around. It works in a browser because of the `systemjs` configuration:

```
// system.conf.js
System.config({
  map: {
    app: "/scripts/app",
    core: "/scripts/core",
  }
}
```

and I can "trick" the compiler by adding `"isolatedModules": true` to tsconfig.json (without this it throws an error), but in `Visual Studio Code` the `Cannot find module` error persists and I lose code-hinting. I heard there are some solutions with typings in `node_modules` folder, but wasn't able to find any working examples.

#### Anyone knows a way to configure the all these to work together gracefully?

Thanks.

Comment: how does the angular2 knows from where to import `angular2/core` ? will anyone explain me.

Comment: @PardeepJain if you look at the source code of [angular bundle](https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/angular2.dev.js) you can see there's `System.register("angular2/core", ....` and that tells systemjs what to do. You can [find more here](https://github.com/ModuleLoader/es6-module-loader/wiki/System.register-Explained)

Comment: Maybe you can put the common services into different app and you can refer as for node_modules. Also maybe you don't need that maybe levels in one app... (if you remove the core ones, probably you would save already one). Also if you put the structure more functional, than you wouldn't need services folder...

Comment: Just like @eesdil said, you should move the services into a separate package and add it as a dependency to this project. Or create a folder under node_modules/custom_p and add combined.ts files which exports all the service modules by referring them relative in it. eg: export * from '../../app/services/search/search.service' export * from '../../core/services/emitter/emitter.service' In our component, import {EmitterService, SearchService} from 'custom_P/combined'. Not at all recommended as we have to separately maintain this folder in node_modules.

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow up to future visitors, this should be fixed in TypeScript 2.0. The configuration that you're looking for is to set the `baseUrl` or `paths` properties in your `tsconfig.json`. If you unconditionally want to match everything to some path in `scripts`, use something like:

```
{
    "baseUrl": "./src/scripts"
}
```

If it's only `core` and `app` that you want to use specially, use

```
{
    "baseUrl": "./src/scripts",
    "paths": {
        "app/*": ["app/*"],
        "core/*": ["core/*"]
    }
}
```