# SystemJS, Browser Sync Setup

Tags: javascript, html, angular, systemjs

I am trying to follow the angular 2  setup guide and am having issues. I am using browsersync and I cannot seem to figure out how to get this code to work.

```
 <script>
   .......
  System.import('./app/boot')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
  </script>
```

The application cannot find /app/boot.js because I am serving up the application using a gulp build process. I cannot access any directories with my "gulp serve" build process, and browser sync is being used. How can I go about using SystemJS in combination with browser sync so that it can find my boot.js file?

Sorry if this is a easy question. I am new to this kind of build process and normally it would be straightforward to just include the file. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you are not posting you code from where we detect the whats error is in your code. but yes gulp with browsersync is a very good combination to make our project run smoothly. i think you are not importing your bootstrap file properly that's may be the error.

still me to used same project setup for my project. i used gulp task with the browsersync in the angular2 you can refer to my repository for the help. this repo may help you to figure out whats the error

> https://github.com/MrPardeep/Angular2-DatePicker

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34895369/options-for-importing-modules-in-angular2-ts#comment57529003_34895369 hope it helps you  !

Comment: and also don't miss this amazing video to watch for workflow with gulp.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7xOubdqyqaY

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues after changing my build process to compile everything into a dist folder instead of root. I tried adjusting baseUrl in System.config, adding maps, paths, manually adding the .js extension to imports etc.

**Lessons I learned:**

1. The sequence of loading scripts and configuring libraries is crucial.
2. System.config needs to be set before including Rx & angular libraries.
3. Then you can import and bootstrap app.

Following @pardeep-jain advice to look at his datepicker repo this worked for me.

```
<!-- 1. Load libraries -->
<!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
<script src="js/libs/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/system-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/system.src.js"></script>

 <script>
    System.config({
        defaultJSExtensions: true,
         map: {
            rxjs: '/node_modules/rxjs'
        },
        packages: {
            rxjs: {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
  </script>

<script src="js/libs/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/router.dev.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/http.dev.js"></script>

<script>
    System.import('js/boot');
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
</head>
<base href="/">
<!-- 3. Display the application -->
<body>
<app>Loading...</app>
```